# Device mounted read/write, but can't delete files

Tags: mount

Please have a look on the attached.
What could be done to solve it?

```
[root@LAB-oam-blade-3 tomcat]# mount
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext3 (rw)
[...]
/dev/mapper/TOMCATp1 on /opt/nls/float/tomcat type ext3 (**rw**)
[root@LAB-oam-blade-3 tomcat]# pwd
/opt/nls/float/tomcat
[root@LAB-oam-blade-3 tomcat]# touch test.test
touch: cannot touch `test.test': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Please post the output of mount.

Comment: `mount` displays /etc/mtab, which can be out of sync with the reality (for instance when the FS has been remounted ro because of errors). What about `grep /opt/nls/float /proc/mounts` and look in `dmesg` output for errors related to the corresponding `dm-x` device?